# The link of the confirmation email does not work

Tags: angular, ruby-on-rails-5

On the local machine, everything works fine for me when I download applications to the server, the confirmation link stops working, when I go over it, I get the error of this page does not exist, I do not know how to fix this error and what it's related to, because in the console There are no mistakes and I can not catch them.

```
import { Component,  Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                       from '@angular/common';
import { AuthService }                    from '../services/auth';

@Component({
  templateUrl: '../templates/confirm-email.html'
})

export class ConfirmEmailComponent {
  loading: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService)) public _authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    this.checkConfirmationToken();
  }

  checkConfirmationToken() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let token: string = params['confirmation_token'];
        if (params && token) {
          this._authService.checkConfirmationToken(token)
            .then(res => {
              this.loading = false;
            });
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

---

```
checkConfirmationToken(confirmation_token: string): Promise<Object> {
const url = `${this.baseUrl}/api/users/${confirmation_token}/confirm_email`;
return this.http.get(url)
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    this.handleError(error, 'Could not confirm email address!');
  });
}
```

---

```
<p>Hello <%= @user.first_name %>!</p>
<p>
Thanks for registering! To confirm your registration click the link below.
</p>
<p>
<%= link_to("Confirm my Email", "#{@origin}/confirm_email?confirmation_token=#{@user.confirm_token}") %>
</p>
```

Comment: If it works on your local machine, the code should be ok. Where does `@origin come from? Does this link work, when you paste it into your browser? How does the url look like?

Comment: I have a file with variables, there are addresses written, so it works. In these files, I change the addresses, so the error is not exactly this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to paste the url into the address field of your browser to check the server settings?

Comment: I.e? Explain what I had to do.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's inserting an invalid address and follow it, so I did it and I get the same error that this page does not exist.

Comment: Why is the address invalid? How does it look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176384/discussion-between-andrea2010-and-thomas-sablik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your local machine you start your app with `ng serve`. This starts webpack and is correctly configured. On heroku you use `"start": "node server.js"` from your package.json. But your server.js contains a wrong path to your index.html.

You have to change

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

to

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```